# Truncating with setw

Tags: c++, stream, truncate, iomanip, setw

Is there a way that I can force `setw` to truncate?

Say that I want to get the output:

> blah blah blee le
>   bu blah blah blee

Is there a way to make this work:

```
string foo{"bu blah blah blee le"};

cout << setw(foo.size() - 3) << foo.data() + 3 << setw(foo.size() - 3) << foo << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

You can switch to unformatted output for this example, though:

```
assert(foo.size() > 3);
cout.write(&foo[3], foo.size() - 3);
cout.write(&foo[0], foo.size() - 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

In the `printf` format specifiers, the precision argument could be used
to specify the maximum number of characters from a string.  In C++,
however, you use the substring operator:

```
std::cout << foo.substr(3) << foo.substr(0, foo.size() - 3) << std::endl;
```

(Of course, for the first, you could also use `foo.c_str() + 3`.)