# How to take first 5 numbers of float

Tags: c++, floating-point, tostring

```
float number=15.555555;
printf("FIRST FIVE NUMBERS%f",number);
```

Desired ouput:

> FIRST FIVE NUMBERS15555

Actual output:

> FIRST FIVE NUMBERS15.555555

How do I get the 5 digit number and discard the decimal point?

For example:

> 123.43213 -> 12343
>
> 1.5634567 -> 15634

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  The question is not clear.  Do you really want to print out 15555? not 15.555?

Comment: @Trent The question is clear, you are just tired.

Comment: Do you want `15555` or `15.555` as output? Please edit your question.

Comment: What if you don't have 5 digits, e.g. 15.?

Comment: @Columbo I believe this is a good question. I have edited it and would like to see it reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without elegance, some brute force and rounding, you might do:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double number = 15.555555;
    while(100000 <= number) number /= 10;
    while(number < 10000) number *= 10;
    // 10000.x <= number < 100000
    number = round(number);
    if(100000 <= number) number = round(number/10);
    std::cout << number << '\n';
}
```

Note: Only for numbers greater than zero.

Comment: Well,when it rounds my number,last digit (5) changes into 6 ...So instead of 15555 i get 15556 :/

Comment: @user3751721 you might use 'trunc' instead

Comment: @DieterLücking You should probably check that number is greater than 1. This solution gets wrecked pretty hard if it's not.

Comment: @JonathanMee I don't see that, but a negative (zero) number, indeed!

Comment: @DieterLücking Yup, sorry that should have read greater than 0.

Comment: @DieterLücking Lol, I guess that's one way to fix the answer, I was looking at patching the code using `log` but that goes haywire if you have negatives too.

Comment: @JonathanMee I avoided that, there might be some clever alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do something like this:

```
cout << "FIRST FIVE NUMBERS" << to_string(15.555555).substr(0, 5);
```

That won't round or anything but maybe it's what you want?

**EDIT:**

Per [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit)'s comment I think the desired result can be obtained from:

```
string foo = to_string(15.555555);

for_each(foo.begin(), advance(foo.begin(), min(5, foo.size())), [](const char& i){if(i != '.')cout << i});
```

Comment: Strip the decimal point and you're there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Is that what he wants? It seems like he just used %f so print the whole thing? Ha, I learned this from your answer this morning!

Comment: According to both of the examples in the question, yes.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean about this morning

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah took that to mean an American comma: 1,000,000

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit http://stackoverflow.com/a/27380559/2642059

Comment: Oh that I see :) Oh my god I haven't moved since then :(